# Responsive Navbar not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working. When you click on the + sign, nothing happens when its supposed to display a menu. I believe the JS is the problem.

```
    $('.resToggle').click(function() {
    $('nav[role=navigation]').toggleClass('active');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETyEu/

Comment: You have no `active` class in your CSS.. Also your Fiddle isn't set up to load `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare your class `.active` with the appropriate `display` declaration and you must add `display: none;` to your `.nav[role=navigation]`

http://jsfiddle.net/ETyEu/